# MVC3 Auto Generated code error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

HI i am doing a MVC 3 application. I am using Entity framwork database approach first method. So all the code is generated automatically. But the problem is when i click on "Edit", "Details" and "Delete" link i get this error.

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'Fin_trial_06.Controllers.AuthorController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters.
```

My controller code is :

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        Author authors = _entities.Authors.Single(n => n.Author_ID == id);
        return View(authors);
    }

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        return View(_entities.Authors.Find(id));
    }


    // POST: /Author/Edit/

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
      public ActionResult Edit(int id, Author aut)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return View("AuthorNotFound"); 
        try
        {
            _entities.Entry(aut).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _entities.SaveChanges();

            TempData["Message"] = "You have successfully Editied Author";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }


 public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        return View(_entities.Authors.Find(id));
    }


    // POST: /Author/Delete/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, Author aut)
    {
        try
        {

            _entities.Entry(aut).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            _entities.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Help Please ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the message seems rather clear

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
      public ActionResult Edit(int id, Author aut)
    {
        if (id == null)
```

You can't enter the action if id == null.

Small consequence :

```
if (id == null)
```

is useless

Solution :
Wether you say that id is an

```
int ?
```

or you don't forget to put an hidden field for your Id in your Edit view

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point in that method to see if an id is being passed to your edit function.  If its not then your view is wrong and not passing the id of the item you want edited. If you post your view code I could tell you where its failing.

Comment: @Raphael Making the parameter null-able isn't going to solve his problem.  If he passes a null id to an edit function, how will the function know which item to edit?